# java program crashes when It doesn't find right match

Tags: java, swing, postgresql, crash

Actually I never had problem like this but this time it makes me uncomfortable.

The program takes a text field from the user and it searches for a right match from SQL which is PostgreSQL. It works fine but when I input something that isn't in the database, the program crashes or something happening, I mean it is not responding to anything. If it might help here is the relevant part of code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String path = null;
    JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if (clicked == loadButton) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = connect.prepareStatement("select * from databank where code=?");
            st.setString(1, field.get(0).getText());
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < field.size(); i++) {
                    if (i < 7)
                        field.get(i).setText(rs.getString(i + 1));
                    else if (i > 6 && i < 10)
                        field.get(i).setText(Double.toString(rs.getDouble(i + 1)));
                    else if (i > 9 && i < 14)
                        field.get(i).setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(i + 1)));
                    else if (i > 13)
                        field.get(i).setText(rs.getString(i + 1));
                    path = rs.getString(15);
                }
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Code = 0020");
        } finally {
            imageHold.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(imageHold);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? How can I solve this?

**Edit:**

This is the stacktrace.

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.awt.image.FileImageSource.getDecoder(FileImageSource.java:53)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

Comment: And also indicate which line causes the exception. Please try to make this question as complete and answerable as possible.

Comment: `updateComponentTreeUI` isn't doing what you think it is, it should NEVER be used to perform basic updates to the UI state and is very inefficient

Comment: @madprogrammer really ? shouldn't I use them ? what do you prefer ?

Comment: You haven't printed the complete stacktrace, in particular the part that involves your code, nor have you indicated which line causes the exception. Again, please help us.

Comment: @VivianMaya combinations of `revalidate` and `repaint` based on what you are trying to do...

Comment: The problem is not in your database accessing code.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels this is the full of stacktrace, there is no more of it.

Comment: which one is line no.138 ?

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor: that line won't help as that's line 138 of Java's core class FileInputStream.java.

Comment: It looks like the value `path` is `null` when called by `imageHold.setIcon( new ImageIcon( path ) );` (at a guess)

Comment: Time to use a debugger me thinks.

Comment: @madprogrammer yes yes, u get it right which is I was posting. thanks for your attentions guys,I'm greatful.

Comment: Why I got -2 ? If you tell me why I will remember what I did wrong and it avoids next mistakes.

Comment: "If you tell me why I will remember what I did wrong and it avoids next mistakes" if you hover your mouse arrow over down-vote button you will see when it should be used, and one of cases is when question "is unclear". In case of this question stacktrace you posted is not complete, it lacks most important information: which line in *your code* throws exception and what code this line contains, so we can only play in guess-where-my-error-is game which not many people like.

Comment: @Pshemo first of all,thank you for your message to clear, but you think I lie ? as I said this is the stacktrace of all. Program doesn't output any more stacktrace.

Comment: @VivianMaya I am not saying you are lying, you can simply not see rest of stacktrace. I don't know which tool you are using to run your code (maybe console) so it is hard to suggest you any hints, but it is definitely not entire stacktrace.

Comment: @Pshemo It is console, but it is really interesting, nevermind thank you again next time I try to keep this in my mind.

Comment: Actually you probably should try to find rest of stacktrace and include it in your question. Without it you are risking that it will be closed since (1) we are unable to reproduce your problem (2) we can't say what your problem actually is. Maybe consider including [simplified version of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces your problem and stacktrace based on that version.

Comment: what do you prefer to find it when it only outputs those ? what should I suppose to do ?

Comment: Consider wrapping your code with `try{yourCode}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}` block. If that will not help add `System.out.println(e.getCause());` in *catch* block.

Comment: Actually preferred way would be probably using IDE (like Eclipse) and its debugger. This way you could step through each line of your code and see where exactly you are getting NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem, when my image column is null on my database,

> imageHold.setIcon( new ImageIcon( path ) );

this makes nullpointer exception.

And I did :

```
if( path != null )
    imageHold.setIcon( new ImageIcon( path ) );
```

and problem solved.

Comment: Actually, your code risks leaving resources open and reducing the efficiency of your program, take a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977123/db2-and-java-adding-data-to-database-through-gui/27977211#27977211) for more information on better resource management...